# How does CommandManager.RequerySuggested work?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, input, keyboard, mouse

The MSDN only states that

> *Occurs when the CommandManager detects conditions that might change the ability of a command to execute.*

However I can't seem to find any traces of how this works, what I should be aware of / avoid etc...
Does it just listen for input? (i.e.: mouse moves, keys pressed and so on)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I cannot tell you exactly what events the `CommandManager` listens to. However, I can tell you that you should **be careful when using the `CommandManager` in connection with asynchronous operations**. I had the following problem when I used the `CommandManager` in my `ICommand` implementations:

I had a button bound to an `ICommand` which triggered an asynchronous operation which increased a value. Now, the button/`ICommand` should be disabled (i.e. its `CanExecute()` method should return `false`) if the value had reached a certain limit. The problem was: The `CommandManager` called my `CanExecute()` method right after the button had been clicked and the asynchronous operation had been started. This asynchronous operation did not take long, but it was long enough to get its result *after* the `CommandManager`'s check, so that the limit check in `CanExecute()` was done using the old value. Therefore, the button remained enabled although the limit was actually reached. The funny thing was, after you clicked anywhere in the UI, the button now got disabled because the `CommandManager` checked the `ICommand` once again and now the new value was checked against the limit.
Actually, I think the `CommandManager` waited around 50ms after the button click until it performed the check of the `ICommand`, but I am not quite sure about that.

My solution was to force the `CommandManager` to check the `ICommand` again by calling the [`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) method in my ViewModel right after I received the result of the async operation.
 **Update:** Please note that this method must be called on the UI thread, otherwise it will have no effect! *(Thanks to midspace for this comment)*

Comment: It should be noted since you are running an Async call, that the CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() must be called in the UI thread, otherwise from personal experience, it does nothing.

Comment: It seems to me that in this circumstance you should not use CommandManager.RequerySuggested as the SOLE trigger for your CanExecuteChanged event.

Clearly your code knows when the async operation completes. It should use that completion to raise your command's CanExecuteChanged. It may be that CommandManager.RequerySuggested has great ideas AS WELL so maybe you should use those in addition.

Answer (score 6):

In that case .NET Reference Source is your friend. Although its badly commented you can still get some ideas about the internal processing.

In the internal [CommandDevice](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandDevice.cs) class you find a method PostProcessInput which invokes the InvalidateRequerySuggested. The name of this method lets assume that the InvalidateRequerySuggested method is invoked on every input event. I'm sure there is further processing and filtering so that your CanExecute method is actually  not invoked on every call to InvalidateRequerySuggested.

Comment: The URL has changed to https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandDevice.cs (I couldn't submit the edit, because it involves less than 6 characters.

Comment: @MikeRosoft I made your change.