# When does WPF decide to requery commands whether they can execute?

Tags: wpf, command

When does WPF requery commands whether they can execute?
Debugger reports it happens quite often. 
But what is the exact set of conditions?

Comment: I think it depends on the type of command. A `RelayCommand` usually requeries `CanExecuteChanged()` anytime any property changes (I think by running [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) anytime a property changes), while a `DelegateCommand` does not and you have to manually have to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` when a property it relies on changes. Also, all commands are re-evaluated when they are bound, so something like  hiding then showing a window will often trigger a requery

Comment: A little more on the topic: [How does CommandManager.RequerySuggested work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763630/how-does-commandmanager-requerysuggested-work) and [What is the actual task of CanExecuteChanged and CommandManager.RequerySuggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634777/what-is-the-actual-task-of-canexecutechanged-and-commandmanager-requerysuggested)

Comment: Nice topic on the subject here:http://robburke.net/2008/04/wpf-command-pattern-when-does-it-query-canexecute/

Comment: [here is a bunch of calls to InvalidateRequerySuggested()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,fb01095b2fe73140)

Comment: @CornelMarian working link: https://robburke.net/wpf-command-pattern-when-does-it-query-canexecute/

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR version of it is that the CanExecute methods are called when certain inputs events occur on the Window. There are primarily Keyboard and Mouse events.

So anytime someone clicks or presses a key, **ALL** commands are invalidated by the CommandManager (by raising the [CommandManager.RequerySuggested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx) event). This is the reason it is important to keep CanExecute methods fast.

It is also possible to handle this yourself by creating a custom `ICommand` implementation that does not use the CommandManager for the `CanExecuteChanged` event.