# GUI of a WPF application is freezing

Tags: wpf, user-interface

The Whole GUI is loaded. After clicked on certain button, the GUI is not responsive: any buttons are no response. If I switch to other app and switch back, the GUI is OK immediately.
Behind the clicked button, it is a handle sending requests to back end. I debugged app, and data has always been returned.
Since the app is huge and I'm not familiar with it, I cannot extract a simple model of sending requests and processing data.I wonder possible causes, since I have no idea now.

Best regards,

-----Add More-----

The back end request sending is in a threadpool thread; when getting data, no UI controls are updated directly. Only presenters (view model) are updated, which are binding to UI control.

Comment: We will not be able to help you much without some details. Can you add details about what happens on click on the button? Also, you mention it is a huge app, could there be any processes running on the dispatcher thread which would probably be halted/closed on application lose focus and therefore it seems ok when you get focus back.

Comment: You are going to have to use a `Profiler` as any answers we give will be guesses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think as [sa-ddam213](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849109/sa-ddam213) have suggested and I too believe that you are executing a code block in background [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) or [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

**I think problem is that**
 - On button click, start execution in background.
 - You have kept a flag for checking if background process is running for `CanExecute()` for the Button's `Command`.
 - UI checks `CanExecute()` for the Button's `Command` for a while then does not as mentioned in another question here - [Is Josh Smith's implementation of the RelayCommand flawed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281566/is-josh-smiths-implementation-of-the-relaycommand-flawed).
 - Process returns in background.
 - UI does not knows the background process is completed and as it has stopped checking the `CanExecute()` for the Button's `Command`, UI will not come to know itself.. (you need to tell it)
 - Therefore UI is not responding but when user will click somewhere in the application or do an in-out as you said, it will back again.

**Solution**
- By using [InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) method you can invoke the command requery on UI thread so UI will recheck the `CanExecute()` for each `Control` and/or `Button` `Command`.

```
// Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

> The [InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) method forces the [CommandManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616838(v=vs.100).aspx) to raise the RequerySuggested event. The RequerySuggested event informs a command source to query the command it is associated with to determine whether or not the command can execute.

For more refer:
 - [How does CommandManager.RequerySuggested work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764022/468718)
 - [MSDN - CommandManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616838(v=vs.100).aspx)
 - [MSDN - CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx)

Comment: Do you mean the CanExecute() is released by GC as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281566/is-josh-smiths-implementation-of-the-relaycommand-flawed), so UI stops checking?

Comment: Have you tried executing `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` on UI Dispatcher instance after the background process finishes.. ?

Comment: I tried but didn't work. `     var syncContext = DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Current;
    if (null == syncContext)
        syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    syncContext.Post(
        (state) =>
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); 
        },
        null);`

Comment: I think try using Dispatcher this way to invoke the CommandManager `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { //some code });`. And do post your findings or solution, if any you have found.. :D

Comment: Your suggestion is not work for my case, but it opens my eye and useful. The cause in my case is a fault of existing styles; my new adding conflict with it. I will add more detail later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a wild guess but try dropping the priority of the logic inside your click event

Example

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate
    {
        // all your code here.
    });
}
```

Comment: Possibly is it not even done async with a begin invoke and hence the dispatcher thread is just busy and blocked.

Comment: The back end request sending is in a threadpool thread; when getting data, no UI controls are updated directly. Only presenters (view model) are updated, which are binding to UI control.