# How to prevent CommandManager from invoking CanExecute whenever there is UI interaction?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, relaycommand

Our UI currently has a lot of controls that are bound to commands with some complex `CanExecutes`. The problem we are facing is that whenever `CommandManager` determines that the UI needs to be re-evaulated, all commands run their `CanExecute`, which in turn, causes quite a performance hit for specific scenarios.

Reading this post: [How does CommandManager.RequerySuggested work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763630/how-does-commandmanager-requerysuggested-work)

It seems that the `CommandManager` will re-evaulate on simple key down, mouse move events, etc. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, and instead, have the command manager re-evaluate when manually invoked?

Comment: I don't think you can. `CanExecute` should not contain any complex functionality. Maybe you could create a bool variable that will tell you if it can be executed or not and change this variable when the conditions change?

Comment: And when/where would you invoke it?

Comment: @Dzyann, a good scenario would be when a specific event is finished running (or gets raised), then have all commands 're-evaluate'

Comment: I would leave everything as it is and add additional validation to the specific places that are causing issues. Consider that in the future changing the default behavior of the CommandManager can cause all kind of issues. An unaware programmer adding logic to certain places and never getting fired. I would imagine that only certain parts of your code are causing performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution might be to implement a simpler version of the `RelayCommand` class that simply stores the event handlers itself and exposes a public method to fire them when appropriate:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    // Further ICommand implementation omitted...

    public void Invalidate()
    {
        var handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

You then call the following in your viewModel to re-evaluate the command:

```
fooCommand.Invalidate();
```

Of course, this leaves you with the opposite problem that you now have to manually re-evaluate all commands...

**Edit**

To elaborate on the comments, most `RelayCommand`'s implement the `CanExecuteChanged` event like this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

When the UI subscribes to the command's `CanExecuteChanged` event it is actually being indirectly subscribed to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event which is why your `CanExecute` method is being called every time the `CommandManager` suggest a re-query.

The simpler `RelayCommand` I have suggested avoids this problem by not subscribing to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event.

Comment: Ben, I can see how this will provide a mechanism for manually invoking, but I do not understand how this prevent CommandManager from invoking automatically based on UI interaction.

Comment: It won't stop the `CommandManager` but it doesn't matter. The simplified `RelayCommand` does not pass any registered event handlers through to the `CommandManager` meaning the UI won't re-evaluate the command every time the `RequerySuggested` event is fired.

Comment: Ben, this provided a mechanism for my issue. thanks!