# How to trigger button command whenever my value from combobox is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combo box and a button. I want whenever I choose 1 of the item from it, the button is not disabled

XAML :

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource borderMain}"
                Grid.Row="7"
                Grid.Column="0">
            <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource portNames}}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        x:Name="Port_Selector" Grid.Column="0"
                        Text="Port Selector" Background="White"/>
        </Border>

        <Border Style="{StaticResource borderMain}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="7">
            <Button Content="Connect"
                    Command="{Binding OpenPortCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPort}"
                    Style="{StaticResource buttonMain}"
                    Margin="5"/>
        </Border>
```

Command :

```
public class OpenPortCommand : ICommand
    {
        public OpenPortVM OpenPortVM{ get; set; }

        public OpenPortCommand(OpenPortVM OpenPortVM)
        {
            this.OpenPortVM = OpenPortVM;
        }

        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            string? portCom = parameter as string;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(portCom))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            OpenPortVM.ConnectPort();
        }
    }
```

I already debug it and check the value from variable that I using for binding `SelectedPort` and it has a value on it but somehow, the CommandParameter for my button not detected so `CanExecute` method is not run properly. Am i missing something?

**Update**

expected :
[image]

result:
[image]

**Update 2**

breakpoint on Setter:
[image]

breakpoint on `CanExecute`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OpenPortCommand` is missing the possibility to actually raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event. I suggest following:

```
public class OpenPortCommand : ICommand
{
    public OpenPortVM OpenPortVM{ get; set; }

    public OpenPortCommand(OpenPortVM OpenPortVM)
    {
        this.OpenPortVM = OpenPortVM;
    }

    // Leave this event as is, don't do an explicit implementation        
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChange() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    
    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter as string);

    // rest ommitted
}
```

In your ViewModel's `SelectedPort` property:

```
public string SelectedPort
{
    get => _selectedPort;
    set
    {
        _selectedPort = value;
        // call your OnPropertyChanged( ... );
        OpenPortCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

In the XAML I've simplified the binding of the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property like this:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}"/>
```

Comment: when you say "rest ommited" why I need to remove that? I mean, I need to call `OpenPortVM.ConnectPort();` method to execute another function

Comment: I have ommitted the rest to keep the code short, you will of course need the rest.

Comment: ah I see, I thought u were removed the rest. Anyway, I tried with ur code but I still confused about `CanExecuteChange` what does that code do? because it doesn't exist in current context

Comment: It's a typo, it should be CanExecuteChange**d** (the name of the event). I'll correct it in the answer.

Comment: hey, it's still not changing the button state. The button still disabled even I already choose the item from the combo box

Comment: Was my assumption correct, that `SelectedPort` is a string property? If you put a breakpoint in the setter of this property, get's the breakpoint hint? Also put one in `CanExecute` method of the command.

Comment: yes you right, it's a String property. I updated the post with the result as u requested, please kindly to check it. thanks

Comment: I've update the CanExecute method of the command, not sure if it solves the problem (I've never used that nullable types in newer .NET releases). Anyways, it is working for me in a .NET 6 project as expected. You have a bug in the setter of the property, it should be `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPort));`, but this is not the cause of command not being updated. Your binding to ´SelectedPort` is TwoWay, why do you need that? Are you setting somewhere the property value in your VM? If it still doesn't work for you, you'll need to show more code.

Comment: Oh u right. It should be `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPort));` not `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(portSelected));`. It works as expected, thanks Steve for ur assist.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues:

1. The most critical one, which actually prevents your code from executing properly, is the way you raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event. Instead of passing in the property name, you currently pass in the name of the backing field.

Instead of

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(portSelected));
```

it must be

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPort));
```

To simplify the event invocation your invocator should use the `CallerMemberName` attribute:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
```

Then call the method `OnPropertyChanged` without any parameter, as the property name is now automatically detected:

```
OnPropertyChanged();
```

2. The method `RaiseExecuteChangedCommand` is redundant. Your `ICommand` implementation of the `CanExecuteChanged` event delegates event handlers to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event (which is correct). The `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event is raised automatically by the WPF framework and because of the event delegation the framework will also raise `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` (because you attach all `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` handlers to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event using `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value`). If you don't want the framework to raise the CanExecuteChanged event for you you must remove the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value` part i.e. don't attach client handlers to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event. Because now you will raise it explcitly from your `RaiseExecuteChangedCommand`  method. So you can't have both. Either raise `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` explicitly or let the `CommandManager` do it for you.

Comment: Wow that's a great explanation, gonna take this as my personal note. Also u right I made a mistake on `onPropertyChanged` it should be `SelectedPort` instead `portSelected`. Thanks there

Comment: A side note regarding 2): I have suggested not to use `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` because it is a blackbox how exactly it works. It can cause some unexpected behavior and is calling the CanExecute methods of the commands too many times unnecessarily (which could also be expensive, depending on what the CanExecute methods actually do). See for example [How does CommandManager.RequerySuggested work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2763630/10318835). I personally like the deterministic way, raising the CanExecuteChange event only if it's really needed.

Comment: @Steeeve CommandManager clearly adds convenience to the application. It strips off the complete logic to handle command states. Especially in an MVVM scenario you don't want the view model to participate in view logic. The CanExecuteChanged event only serves for the view (the ICommandSource implementations) to control its state. For example it allows the button to disable itself. Such state is not of interest for the view model.

Comment: @Steeeve It makes sense to off-load the logic to the CommandManager so that the view model must not track the conditions that influence this state. The performance impact is neglectible on todays machines. Usually you don't do expensive computations in the delegate. There are more critical UI related optimizations to consider. It never occurred that we had to change the commanding infrastructure in order to fix UI related performance issues. There is no need to avoid the CommandManager to handle the command states for you.

Comment: @BionicCode I'm still not convinced :) I had to debug some, let's call it 'suboptimal' ViewModel, where every keystroke in a textbox was causing a delay and a CPU usage peek, making fluent typing impossible. It was caused by dosens of commands having some expensive work in CanExecute being called by CommandManager. But as I wrote, it is only my opinion, just a hint to keep in mind when using CommandManager.

Comment: @Steeeve Hard to believe. The problem is not the CommandManager but the irrational *"dosens of commands having some expensive work in CanExecute"*. This is ridiculous. Wonder what expensive work a simple CanExecute predicate can do. If it for example has to communicate  to a server than you have a different, a serious design problem here. Calling CanExecuteChanged only once during the lifetime of the application of course cloaks this bad design. CanExecute does not consume any significant resources if implemented properly. But I'm not trying to convince you here.

Comment: @Steeeve I was just replying to your comment that was using performance as the reason to drop the CommandManager.